# Resolve dependencies between jQuery and jQueryUI with dojo require

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dojo, dependencies, require

First of all, I'm using a custom build of dojo framework `(v1.9.0)` done with `build.dojotoolkit.org/`, with my required modules, included the `loader` module.

I have a question related to the `dojo.require` loader and the jQuery framework. The main question is about how can I to resolve the dependency between jQuery and jQueryUI (asn by extension with all the other plugins for jQuery).

I've been trying to do a simple test by loading them through this way:

```
require({
   async: true,
   baseUrl: 'js/GUIFramework/',
   tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
   paths: {
      dojo: 'external/dojo/dojo-1.9',
      jQuery: 'external/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
      jQueryUI: 'external/jquery/jquery-ui.min'
   }
},
[
   'jQuery',
   'jQueryUI'
],
    function (jQuery, jQueryUI) {
        var test = jQuery;
    });
```

But when the callback function is executed, after trying to load the modules, I have this error (see with firebug):
`"ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" in jquery-ui.min.js (línea 5)`

I've seen that other loaders, like RequireJS, have a configuration option called "`shim`" which specifically load files with non "define" function defined. But I haven't seen anything similar with the `dojo.require`.

Do you how to solve this for this specific case and for others similar that may occur?

Thank you,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After navigating a little more and looked for a `"shim"` implementation in Dojo, I have found a plugin, `"use.js"` (http://documentup.com/tbranyen/use.js) which seems to have the same functionality that a `"shim"` in RequireJS, and by the tests I've done until the moment, it seems to work fine.

I hope it to be helpful for anyone.

**EDIT:** The link I posted to `use.js` plugin is no longer available. Now you can see it [here](https://github.com/tbranyen/use-amd).

Answer (score 2):

A shim is actually nothing more than doing the following:

```
define([], function() {
    return jQuery;
});
```

jQuery and many other JavaScript libraries/frameworks add themself to the global scope, jQuery adds both the `$` sign as `jQuery`. Now you just define your own jQuery shim module which returns that global variable.

Comment: Your answer has opened my eyes and I have finally found a solution near to your comments. I have choose to define intermediate modules where I load the no AMD files I need and the jQuery plugins. By this way I'm sure to load every dependency of a file before start to load it.